# Meaning of "would" in requests and conditional sentences

Tags: difference, modal-verbs, conditional-constructions

Can we use *would* without an *if* clause as below. How can it be right?

> A) Would you help me to open the door?
>   B) Yes, of course

or it's full form is

> If you had mind, Would you help me to open the door?

Please explain

Comment: Not sure if you meant "If you have time" or "If you don't mind". "If you had mind" is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

**would** is the simple past of **will**. We use the simple past to describe things that happened in the past:

> We knew that it wouldn't be easy

We also use the simple past of will for [backshifting of reported speech](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/quick-grammar/reported-speech-1)

> He said that he would be busy tomorrow

For almost all verbs, the simple past can also be used as a subjunctive for hypothetical conditionals.

> If you are broke, I will give you some money - *real*
>   If you were broke, I would give you some money - *hypothetical*

For modal verbs (can/could, shall/should, will/would), we also use it to make a request or suggestion more polite. To tell somebody to do something, you can use an imperative:

> Help me to open the door.

You can phrase this slightly more politely by saying

> Will you help me to open the door?

To make that very polite, you use the simple past of **will**:

> Would you help me to open the door?

Here are some more examples from [this definition of **would**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/would):

> Would you mind sharing a room?
>   Would you like me to come with you?
>   Would you like some cake?

It is possible to use **would** in a conditional sentence (see the appropriate section of the link above) but this is a different meaning to making a polite request.

> What would you do if you lost your job?
>   If I'd had time, I would have gone to see Graham.

Note that there are several other meanings of **would**.